# PHP 5.4 - 'closure $this support'

Tags: php, closures

I see that the new planned features for PHP 5.4 are: traits, array dereferencing, a JsonSerializable interface and something referred to as '`closure $this support`'

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php#Release_history

While the others are either immediately clear (JsonSerialiable, array dereferencing) or i looked up the specifics (traits), I am not sure what 'closure $this support' is.  I have been unsuccessful googling for it or finding anything about it on php.net

Does anyone know what this is supposed to be?

If i had to guess, it would mean something like this:

```
$a = 10; $b = 'strrrring';
//'old' way, PHP 5.3.x
$myClosure = function($x) use($a,$b)
             {
                 if (strlen($x) <= $a) return $x;
                 else return $b;
             };

//'new' way with closure $this for PHP 5.4
$myNewClosure = function($x) use($a as $lengthCap,$b as $alternative)
                 {
                     if(strlen($x) <=  $this->lengthCap)) return $x;
                     else 
                     {
                         $this->lengthCap++;  //lengthcap is incremented for next time around
                         return $this->alternative;
                     }
                 };
```

The significance (even if this example is trivial) being that in the past once the closure is constructed the bound 'use' variables are fixed.  With 'closure $this support' they are more like members you can mess with.

Does this sound correct and/or close and/or reasonable?  Does anyone know what this 'closure $this support' means?

Comment: FWIW, 5.4 is not yet the *official* name of PHP trunk -- it's still internally called "5.3.99" and there is some controversy as to whether it will really be 5.4 or not (vs 6.0, which would then be unrelated to the big Unicode rewrite "6.0" branch).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This was already planned for PHP 5.3, but

> For PHP 5.3 $this support for Closures was removed because no consensus could be reached how to implement it in a sane fashion. This RFC describes the possible roads that can be taken to implement it in the next PHP version.

It indeed means you can refer to the object instance ([live demo](http://eval.in/private/49dbe38b3450ec))

```
<?php
class A {
  private $value = 1;
  public function getClosure() 
  {
    return function() { return $this->value; };
  }
}

$a = new A;
$fn = $a->getClosure();
echo $fn(); // 1
```

For a discussion, see the PHP Wiki

- [Closures: Object extension](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/object-extension)

and for historic interest:

- [closures (rfc)](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures)
- [removal-of-this (rfc:closures)](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/removal-of-this)

Comment: oooh, i was going in totally the wrong direction.  you mean '$this' being the instance of `Foo` right?  i thought of '$this' as being the closure itself.  would `use` still be necessary?

Comment: @jon no, using `use` is not even possible. You cannot use $this as lexical variable in any PHP version to date. I updated with the example from the Wiki and a link to a codepad showing the results with the current PHP trunk.

Comment: thanks this is great.  btw - the `public $closure` doesnt do anything and just kind of distracts from your point, which you otherwies demonstrate very well

Comment: i edited that out, hope you dont mind.  links are great btw, ive never really looked at those wiki pages before

Comment: @Gordon - I think jon meant `use` in the general case--not specific to `$this`. AFAIK, `use` will still be necessary to access local variables. I'm looking forward to dropping the `use ($self)` trick. :)

Comment: the problem about the use($self) trick is that it works for public methods only, what we really wanted is to be able to access all members, after all we are talking to $this... it will take a little while until everyone starts using php 5.4, some servers still use 5.2

Comment: For clarity, with reference of the provided RFC link (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/object-extension) the implementation in PHP 5.4a+ most closely resembles approach **A**, **B**, **C**, or **D**? I'm assuming **A**, however if there are any caveats that provide the dynamic rebinding behavior prescribed by **D**, that would be fantastic.

Comment: @Bracketworks I am not 100% sure but people more involved with the decision told me they think it's A.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon - That's what I figured. Hopefully the PHP docs will be updated soon, to include something definitive.

Comment: Actually, `$closure->bindTo($object);` appears to perform the task of rebinding manually, and should be a fantastic addition to PHP.

Answer (score 53):

One thing that Gordon missed is re-binding of `$this`. While what he described is the default behaviour, it is possible to re-bind it.

**Example**

```
class A {
    public $foo = 'foo';
    private $bar = 'bar';

    public function getClosure() {
        return function ($prop) {
            return $this->$prop;
        };
    }
}

class B {
    public $foo = 'baz';
    private $bar = 'bazinga';
}

$a = new A();
$f = $a->getClosure();
var_dump($f('foo')); // prints foo
var_dump($f('bar')); // works! prints bar

$b = new B();
$f2 = $f->bindTo($b);
var_dump($f2('foo')); // prints baz
var_dump($f2('bar')); // error

$f3 = $f->bindTo($b, $b);
var_dump($f3('bar')); // works! prints bazinga
```

The closures `bindTo` instance method (alternatively use the static `Closure::bind`) will return a new closure with `$this` re-bound to the value given. The scope is set by passing the second argument, this will determine visibility of private and protected members, when accessed from within the closure.

- [PHP: Closure](http://php.net/closure)
- [Blog post: Closure Object Binding in PHP 5.4](http://christophh.net/2011/10/26/closure-object-binding-in-php-54/)

Comment: +1 for describing the `bindTo()` functionality, which is a pretty important feature.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to rebind closure created from method?

Answer (score 22):

Building on @Gordon's answer it is posible to mimic some hacky aspects of closure-$this in PHP 5.3.

```
<?php
class A
{
    public $value = 12;
    public function getClosure()
    {
        $self = $this;
        return function() use($self)
        {
            return $self->value;
        };
    }
}

$a = new A;
$fn = $a->getClosure();
echo $fn(); // 12
```

Comment: Yes, but a notable difference is that you can't access any private or protected properties or methods on `$self` from within the closure.

Comment: +1 haha, found this answer a year later and it solved my problem. ;)

Comment: @jgivoni does you means, it is not possible to access private or protected variable in PHP 5.3?

Comment: @Shiro, yes. This workaround for 5.3 only works with public properties.

Comment: @Pacerier, I am not aware of any workaround for accessing non-public properties within closures in PHP 5.3. Best advice is to upgrade to 5.4 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Just building on the other answers here, I think this example will demonstrate what is possible PHP 5.4+:

```
<?php

class Mailer {
    public    $publicVar    = 'Goodbye ';
    protected $protectedVar = 'Josie ';
    private   $privateVar   = 'I love CORNFLAKES';

    public function mail($t, $closure) {
        var_dump($t, $closure());
    }
}

class SendsMail {
    public    $publicVar    = 'Hello ';
    protected $protectedVar = 'Martin ';
    private   $privateVar   = 'I love EGGS';

    public function aMailingMethod() {
        $mailer = new Mailer();
        $mailer->mail(
            $this->publicVar . $this->protectedVar . $this->privateVar,
            function() {
                 return $this->publicVar . $this->protectedVar . $this->privateVar;
            }
        );
    }
}

$sendsMail = new SendsMail();
$sendsMail->aMailingMethod();

// prints:
// string(24) "Hello Martin I love EGGS"
// string(24) "Hello Martin I love EGGS"
```

see: https://eval.in/private/3183e0949dd2db