# PHP and closures

Tags: php, closures

Working a lot with JS I have come to love closures, so I was pleased to learn that there are closures in PHP also. However I just can't get this stuff to work, what's wrong with this piece of code?

```
class Foo {
    public $Bar;
    public function Foo() {
        $this->Bar = function() { echo "Hello World"; };
    }
};

$F = new Foo();
$F->Bar();
```

I keep getting `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Foo::Bar()` errors.

Comment: (a) What you have is an anonymous function, not a closure. (b) Which PHP version are you using? This was introduced in PHP 5.3.

Comment: I believe it has to be >=5.3 as there would have been a parsing error otherwise

Comment: @jlb: Right, just noticed that..

Comment: oops yeah that's what I meant then Felix ;) I'm on version 5.3.6

Comment: FYI: A php class can have a property and function by the same name, so trying to access a property as a function via $this->propname() doesn't adhere to the rules.

Comment: On a side note; If you're using PHP 5+, you should really name your constructor method `__construct` instead of `Foo` :-) While this still works in some cases, it would actually break if you introduce a namespace here.

Answer (score 5):

This has been discussed a lot on SO already (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734011/php-5-4-closure-this-support/5734109#5734109)). This should do the trick:

```
$b = $f->Bar;
$b();
```

Yes, it is that stupid. You could use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func) to put in in one line (see [jlb's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952735/php-and-closures/7952780#7952780)), but the ugliness remains.

Comment: Nice. So much of PHP's class system feels very, say, "ad-hoc", that at least the fact that you should need such a workaround is not a surprise in itself...

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree. These two lines of code are an abomination.

Comment: Yep, the two lines ARE an abomination.. try my solution :)

Comment: @jlb Which is basically the same, but in one line. Doesn't make the fact that `$f->Bar()` does not work any better. :/

Comment: @middus not quite sure what your point is.. call_user_func removes the need for the temporary variable $b

Comment: @jlb Yes, but why should you need to call another function (i.e. `call_user_func`) in order to call your own function? Because you have to work around the ridiculous shortcomings of php. This is sad. Not on your part, but on php's.

Comment: Oh that's really weird. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @middus I'm not exactly sure how this is a shortcoming (see my comment on the question itself)

Comment: @jlb: I think the very fact that PHP distinguishes between "functions" and "user functions" is a sign that something has been "tacked on". The one-liner is probably preferable to this version, but I'm also glad to know that it's possible to call a "user function" with the usual function syntax using this workaround. Oh well.

Comment: @KerrekSB I've never distinguished between functions and user-functions.. what is the difference?

Comment: @jlb: Well, the fact that you need to invoke `call_user_func` to call a *user* function, but just round parentheses to call a "normal" function -- the fact that those two are distinct gives the whole idea a tacked on feel, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB you can call normal and user (i take it you mean user-defined..) functions via call_user_func. call_user_func's purpose is to provide an interface to dynamically determine which function to call (ie. and reduce control statements)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a one-line solution to replace

```
$F->Bar()
```

try this:

```
call_user_func($F->Bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has separation between methods and fields. In fact, you can have a method and a field of the same name at the same time:

```
class Foo {
    public $Bar;
    function Bar() { echo "hello\n"; }
};

$F = new Foo();
$F->Bar = 42;
$F->Bar(); // echoes "hello"
```

So you can see that, to avoid ambiguity, there must be a separate syntax between calling a method with that name, and accessing a field with that name and then calling that as a function.

If PHP had better syntax, they would support `($F->Bar)()`, i.e. function call operator on any expression, but currently only variables can be "called".

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't liking the `$F->Bar` notation for accessing the closure.

If you change this slightly to

```
$t = $F->Bar();
$t();
```

then it works.