# PHP - self, static or $this in callback function

Tags: php, static, callback, anonymous-function, self

Is it possible to access classes/objects reffered as `self`, `static` and `$this` in anonymous callbacks in PHP? Just like this:

```
class Foo {
    const BAZ = 5;
    public static function bar() {
         echo self::BAZ; // it works OK
         array_filter(array(1,3,5), function($number) /* use(self) */ {
             return $number !== self::BAZ; // I cannot access self from here
         });
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it behave as with usual variables, using `use(self)` clause?

Comment: Since PHP 5.4 it is possible to use $this.

Comment: *(related)* [PHP 5.4 - 'closure $this support'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734011/php-5-4-closure-this-support/5734109#5734109)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With PHP5.4 it will be. For now it's not possible. However, if you only need access to public properties, method

```
$that = $this;
function () use ($that) { echo $that->doSomething(); }
```

For constants there is no reason to *not* use the qualified name

```
function () { echo Classname::FOO; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it's not possible to use Classname if I need to substitute static::FOO, i.e late binding.

Comment: Sounds you are more looking for class properties (aka static properties), than constants. However, with the first example in my answer you should be able to call the constant like `$that::FOO`.

Comment: Actually, I think to do what the OP wants with late binding it wouldn't it be: $that=static::FOO;

Comment: @Tim Closures are no objects (actually they are, but thats more an implementation detail and shouldn't concern you), so there is no `static` and `self`, but the last one can easily substituted with the concrete class name. `static` has very limited use anyway and you should think twice, if you _really_ need it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wanted to say. I realise all of the things you are saying. I was pointing out that your response to the OP's request for late static binding won't work. The solution would be to replace the first line of your first codeblock with $that=static::FOO; That will provide late static binding at the closure creation point, which is the best one can do in php 5.3

Comment: @Tim I already understood. Please show me one case for `static::`, that is _not_ related to ORM, ActiveRecord or similar ;) Thats what I want to say: Actually there are no other use-cases, so this workaround does it as well, if you _really_ need it: `$class = get_class($this); $closure = function () use ($class) { echo $class::FOO; }`. Isn't that pretty, but you'll probably never see it anyway :D

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood your objection then. This is all code I would never write though anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use the standard way:

```
Foo::BAZ;
```

or

```
$baz = self::BAZ;
... function($number) use($baz) {
   $baz;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
class Foo {
    const BAZ = 5;
    $self = __class__;
    public static function bar() {
         echo self::BAZ; // it works OK
         array_filter(array(1,3,5), function($number) use($self) {
             return $number !== $self::BAZ; // access to self, just your const must be public
         });
    }
}
```