# PHP Closures - How do I call a class function with $this

Tags: php, closures

I'm having a little trouble with PHP Closures.

Okay, so let's say I have:

```
$router->bind('~/~', function()
{
    print "I'm on the home page";
});

$shel = new Shel($config, $router);
$shel->start();
```

Now, all my functions are called by Shel. Inside Shel, there's a function load(). Is there a way to call Shel::load() from the closure that I've binded, using $this?

Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP 5.4 - 'closure $this support'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734011/php-5-4-closure-this-support)

Comment: I'm on 5.3.8. Gordon, I read through that thread, but I think my issue is a little different, I should have specified in the original post, it's now been updated.

Answer (score 4):

PHP 5.3:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/object-extension

> For PHP 5.3 $this support for Closures was removed because no
>   consensus could be reached how to implement it in a sane fashion. This
>   RFC describes the possible roads that can be taken to implement it in
>   the next PHP version.

So in PHP 5.3 you had to workaround a bit:

```
$that = $this;
$router->bind('~/~', function() use ($that)
{
    print "I'm on the home page";
});
```

For 5.4 you can use just $this.

Comment: I'm on 5.3.8. However, I'm still not entirely sure how that would help? I just realised I forgot to mention one important aspect of the problem, I'll update the post.

Comment: I see, in that case, you'd have to bind *after* you set your $router object into Shel, then you could just use($shel) and call it with $shel->load(). Other way around it's not possible, because the scope is not know to the anonymous function.

Comment: Hm, I see. In that case, should I make my Router class static? That's the easiest way I can see to do it.

Comment: Well yes you'd need to make `load()` static. The class itself cannot be static in PHP.

Comment: Ugh, this is what happens when I take a break from PHP. Haha cheers!