# How to get domain root url in Laravel 4?

Tags: url, laravel-4, root

I'm ready to scream how hard can this be? I've been trying for too long.
If I have http://www.example.com/more/pages/page.php or similar I want to be able to get
www.example.com.

Thats all. So I can use it as I please. This will of course change if on production or development so I want to ascertain it dynamically.

```
Request::root()
```

returns http://www.example.com/more/pages/page.php

```
URL::to('/')
```

returns http://www.example.com/more/pages/page.php

How do I get this? Why am I having so much trouble to do this??

Comment: Try `Request::getHttpHost()`, from your question seems that it's what you need.

Comment: That indeed seems to work as well, great tip. Where did you find that?

Comment: `Request::getHost()` also works.

Comment: url('') - it's so simple

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**UPDATE (2017-07-12)**

A better solution is actually to use `Request::getHost()`

**Previous answer:**

I just checked and `Request::root();` does return `http://www.example.com` in my case, no matter which route I'm on. You can then do the following to strip off the `http://` part:

```
if (starts_with(Request::root(), 'http://'))
{
    $domain = substr (Request::root(), 7); // $domain is now 'www.example.com'
}
```

You may want to double check or post more code (`routes.php`, controller code, ...) if the problem persists.

Another solution is to simply use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

Comment: I do not know what the issue was. Now it seems to be working fine. I testing it for an hour. The only thing I can think of was the vhost in apache on my localhost was not correct. I moved the public folder and did not update this. This may have effected it. But what I described was defiantly happening. I kept returning the URL of the current page. I was going crazy...

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] returns the name of the server host: "The name of the server host under which the current script is executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host." This will not always be the url the user is on, e.g. if you have aliases in your vhosts. Request::root(); works fine in this occassion.

Comment: Better to use a regex because if you ever switch to `https://` then your code is broken.

Comment: If you're looking to parse a url I'd recommend `parse_url`.

Comment: This code is broken if used with any other protocol that doesn't have exactly 4 characters

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer. There is a comment by lowerends on the original question that is much cleaner

Comment: getHost is not a static method. instead use `response()->getHost()` or `$request->getHost()`

Comment: You cant use this anymore. "should not be called statically" error will show

Answer (score 37):

You also may test any of these:

```
Request::server ("SERVER_NAME")
Request::server ("HTTP_HOST")
```

It seems better than making any treatment of

```
Request::root()
```

All right.

Answer (score 37):

In Laravel 5.1 and later you can use

```
request()->getHost();
```

or

```
request()->getHttpHost();
```

(the second one will add port if it's not standard one)

Comment: You can also use request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() to get url with http://

Answer (score 19):

My hint:

1. FIND IF EXISTS in .env:

   `APP_URL=http://yourhost.dev`
2. REPLACE TO (OR ADD)

   `APP_DOMAIN=yourhost.dev`
3. FIND in config/app.php:

   `'url' => env('APP_URL'),`
4. REPLACE TO

   `'domain' => env('APP_DOMAIN'),`

   `'url' => 'http://' . env('APP_DOMAIN'),`
5. USE:

   `Config::get('app.domain'); // yourhost.dev`

   `Config::get('app.url') // http://yourhost.dev`
6. Do your magic!

Comment: P.S.: You free to add any environment variables and use it this way, for example: for api domain, for account domain, for help documentation domain and any others. But, you don't really need to add development domains in .env (like APP_DEV_DOMAIN). Just use another environment (develop.env, behat.env, qa.env etc) with another values.

(sorry for ruenglish)

Answer (score 10):

This is for Laravel 5.1 and I am not sure does it work for earlier versions but if somebody search on Google and lands here it might be handy in middleware handle function gets $request parameter:

```
$request->server->get('SERVER_NAME')
```

outside of middleware handle method you can access it by helper function request()

```
request()->server->get('SERVER_NAME')
```

Answer (score 1):

use directly where you want controller or web.php

```
Request::getHost();
```

Comment: double check your code above getHost() not using $this  object ,you may used $this invalid place like https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154804/11624647

Answer (score -18):

I think you can use `asset('/')`