# PHP using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, function, class, fatal-error

I have the following class:

```
class Decode {
    public $code;
    public $codeStore;
    public $store;
    public $varName;
    public $storeNew = array();
    public $storeNew = array();

    public function __construct($code) {
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->codeStore = $code;
        $this->varName = substr($this->code, 0, 30);
        $this->varName = str_replace("var ", "", $this->varName);
        $this->varName = substr($this->varName, 0, strpos($this->varName, "=[\""));
    }

    public function chrToVar() {
        // The line below is line 38
        $this->code = preg_replace_callback('/'.$this->varName.'\[([0-9]+)\]/', function($matches) { return $this->storeNew[$matches[1]]; }, $this->code);
    }
}

$script = new Decode('stuff');
$script->chrToVar();
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   /var/www/programs/decode.php on line 38

Why is this happening? I suppose it has something to do with the parameter that has the function in `preg_replace_callback`, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: try `function($matches) use($this)`

Comment: possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 5.4 `$this` can be used in anonymous functions and it refers to the current object, simple example:

```
class Decode {
    public $code;

    public function __construct( $code ) {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function chrToVar() {        
        $this->code = preg_replace_callback( '/\w+/', 
            function( $matches ) {              
                var_dump( $this );
            }, $this->code
        );
    }
}

$script = new Decode( 'stuff' );
$script->chrToVar();
```

For version 5.3 you may use a workaround but it only works with public properties:

```
$self = $this;
$this->code = preg_replace_callback( '/\w+/', 
    function( $matches ) use ( $self ) {                
        var_dump( $self );
    }, $this->code
);
```

My advice is to upgrade at least to 5.4 if possible.

More info: [PHP 5.4 - 'closure $this support'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734011/php-5-4-closure-this-support)